# Consider the map $ \ \ f\colon P_{3} \to M_{2 \times 2} \text{ by } f(ax^{3}+bx^{2}+cx+d)=\begin{bmatrix} a+b & d \\ a-c & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Consider the map $f\colon P_{3} \to M_{2 \times 2}$ defined by $$f(ax^{3}+bx^{2}+cx+d)=\begin{bmatrix} a+b & d \\ a-c & 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$

$(i)$ Find the nullity of $f$

$(ii)$ Find the basis of the null space of $f$.

**For the null space $f(ax^{3}+bx^{2}+cx+d)=0$ . But from this how do I find the basis for null space? Please help me.**

Comment: Well the null space will be those polynomials which give you zero matrix, so you consider the polynomials with coefficients such that $a+b = 0$, $a-c = 0$, and $d=0$. From this, you should be able to find a basis, if you remember that the standard basis for $P_3$ looks like $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$.

Answer (score 0):

In order to find the basis of null space we have to actually find for what set of values of coefficients of polynomials results in the function to take zero value,so comparing each entry of the matrix to the zero matrix of order $2$ , we get $a-c =0 , a+b =0 , d =0$,so the polynomial now looks like $a.x^3 - a.x^2 + a.x + 0$ , 
so the basis for the null space is $(x^3,-x^2,x,0)$ . So also the dimension of null space (Nullity) is $1$.

Comment: do you mean by $\{1,-1,1,0\} $ , the vector (1,-1,1,0) ?